# How to check Android System WebView?

Tags: android, webview, crash

There was a recent Android System WebView update that is causing crashes.
How can I check the version of the webview installed by the user? If this is the crashing version, then I will not execute the webview related code.
I can find out the current version, but I need to know the problematic version number.

```
val pm = requireActivity().packageManager
val pi = pm.getPackageInfo("com.google.android.webview", 0)
val currentVersion = pi.versionName
```

Comment: what kind of crash? from what I had face is that the crash happen when the Android System Webview app is updating/installing and at the same time, you open an app that contains Webview

Comment: also, is your way to check if the webview is installed or not in a device valid? I'm kind of had an issue where a device not installed webview and I need to check it from whether the webview is available or not

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I do checking the webview version based on the useragent of the webview, from the userAgent then I do some regex to get the webview version. Here is the code

```
val chromeVersion = extractChromeVersion(webView.settings.userAgentString)
Log.d("chromeVersion", "$chromeVersion")
if (chromeVersion != null && chromeVersion < 100){
   showAlert(chromeVersion)
   return
}
```

...

```
fun extractChromeVersion(userAgent: String): Int? {
    val regex = "Chrome/(\\d+\\.\\d+\\.\\d+\\.\\d+)"
    val matchResult = regex.toRegex().find(userAgent)
    val versionString = matchResult?.groupValues?.get(1)?.split(".")?.get(0)
    return versionString?.toIntOrNull()
}
```